# How to pass additional arguments to the FileSystemEventHandler class to allow for user input?

Tags: python, filesystemwatcher

I am creating a watchdog in python where the user is able to select a folder to monitor. In order to use the selected watch directory I had to pass the variable into both my event handler and the scheduler. My result is below. The program first ask for the direcotry and avoids using any global variables.

**`WATCHDOG.py`**

```
import time
import logging
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler, FileSystemEventHandler


class OnMyWatch:

    def __init__(self, dir):
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.dir = dir 

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.dir, recursive = True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Observer Stopped")

        self.observer.join()



class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, dir): 
        self.dir = dir


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    dir = filedialog.askdirectory()

    watch = OnMyWatch(dir)
    watch.run()
```

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: You just need to add `global WATCH_DESTINATION` as the first line inside your function

Comment: What would you do if someone told you that they’d cut 5% of your paycheck every time you used a global variable? Would you come up with something different then?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: Ah, this is just the motivation I need as even I use globals from time to time!

Comment: You can access global variables anywhere in the module. You only need a `global` statement if you are *writing* to a global variable inside a function. The staticness of your method is irrelevant. What actual problem have you observed?

Comment: I don't get it.  You don't have to add anything.  This code should all work fine.  You'd need a `global` statement only if you wanted to change one of the global variables from inside the function.  Are you getting an error?  If so, can you show us?  If it's with code that you aren't showing, can you show that?

Comment: Thank ya for the advise. I will get rid of the global variables and edit the question if I am still in need.

Comment: No reason not to understand what you're trying to do first, even if you should try not to use globals.  You could use a Class level variable that would be really the same thing just in a different namespace.

Comment: You don't need to declare something a `global` to read its value, only to create the variable or change the object associated with it if that was done outside the function or method. The fact that the method is static has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Is there any chance this question could be reopened? I went back an edited the question to be more clear and concise to what I was initially asking along with updating the code to include a working version. I believe this question could pose valuable information to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer is that any function or method in a module can read its global variables without doing anything special. As long as a function does not use a variable name is its parameter list or assign a value to a variable, it is not in the function namespace and python will look elsewhere for it (perhaps in a class namespace or the module namespace).

More to the point...

Looking at the docs [on_any_event](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler.on_any_event) is not a static method and I don't see any advantage to making it static in your code. `FileSystemEventHandler` is meant to be extended with the information you want for your event handling. Since you want the destination directory to be available in the handler, just create an initializer that puts it there.

I've done a bit of rearranging to put your script level code inside the `if __name__=="__main__":` block and I've extended your classes to keep the data pulled in by the GUI. Now your obserser is decoupled from the GUI and whatever variables it happens to create. You could have more than one observer running in different threads and you could replace the GUI with something else (like a test script) if you'd like.

You can add other data to the classes, this is just the minimum to get your print to work.

```
import time
import logging 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from watchdog.observers import Observer 
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler, FileSystemEventHandler

class OnMyWatch:

    def __init__(self, watch_dir, dest_dir):
        self.watch_dir = watch_dir
        self.dest_dir = dest_dir
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler(self.dest_dir)
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.watch_dir, recursive = True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Observer Stopped")

        self.observer.join()

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self, dest_dir): 
        self.dest_dir = dest_dir

    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print(self.dest_dir)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    WATCH_DIRECTORY = filedialog.askdirectory()
    WATCH_DESTINATION = filedialog.askdirectory()
    watch = OnMyWatch(WATCH_DIRECTORY, WATCH_DESTINATION)
    watch.run()
```

NOTE: Its okay to use global variables like you did on small scripts. The code above is written with future uses in mind, but really its over-designed for a simple script. Some people think that you shouldn't put more into code than than required because predictions about future use are often wrong.

Comment: Is there anything against creating a `def GetDestFold()` and `def GetSourceFold()` within the `Handler` class, i.e., improper coding convention.

Comment: It violates standard python coding conventions but is very close to Microsoft conventions (`getDestFold` I think would be the rule Microsoft uses for methods). I highly favor the python convention but would consider (1) the normal conventions of the organization I am in, and (2) the classes that I am inheriting from. tkinter and watchdog are both standard python so unless you've got a good reason to use Microsoft convention, don't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem maybe.  What you say you want to do just works.  What you have in your code should work.  You could also use a class-level variable, which is really a global too but in the namespace of a particular class.  This code is a simpler example, showing both:

```
SOME_GLOBAL_VARIABLE = "Some Global Variable"

class Handler():

    SOME_CLASS_LEVEL_VAR = "Some Class Level Var"

    @staticmethod
    def some_static_method(event):
        print(SOME_GLOBAL_VARIABLE)
        print(Handler.SOME_CLASS_LEVEL_VAR)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Handler.some_static_method({})
```

Result:

```
Some Global Variable
Some Class Level Var
```

Am I missing the point here?  If I am, sorry about that.

Comment: Actually this answer is perfect! After taking some advice I created a function to request the folders and then I needed to pass them into the static method and was not exactly sure how. Thank you! I will revise my question but your answer should still be appropriate.